# Como enviar valor de campo de formulario a funcion ajax

Tags: html, ajax

Muy buenas, tengo un formulario en html, y me gustaría que al hacer click en un boton, llame a una funcion ajax pasandole el usuario y la clave.

Este es mi formulario.

```
<form  method="post" action="javascript:login();" name="loginForm"  id="loginForm">
          <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"   name="txtUsuario" placeholder="Usuario" required />          
          </div>

         <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
            <input type="password"   class="form-control"  name='txtClave' placeholder="Clave" required />     
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-sm  btn-primary btn-block">Aceptar</button>
        </div>
         </form>
```

Los datos que quiero enviar a la funcion login() son el idUsuario e idCLave.

Muchas gracias. Un saludo

Comment: Se acepta jquery?

Comment: Si, claro jajajajaaj

Comment: Solo una pregunta. Alguna vez has utilizado ajax?

Comment: Si, pero soy muy novato :), lo he arreglado con esta linea variable=$('#idUsuario').val();  Me funciona, imagino que es correcto hacerlo de esta forma. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Publica lo que has intentado y asi se te puede ayudar mejor.

Comment: Tengo dos partes, la primera es el formulario que llama a la funcion login, y la segunda, es la funcion login donde tomo las dos variables de la forma que he puesto arriba. Ya tomando las variables puedo construir la funcion ajax que llamará a un archivo php y hara el trabajo para devolver los resultados. Mi duda era como poder tomar las variables de un form desde una funcion js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba de esta manera, el código esta comentado.

```js
$("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "path/to/your/script.php", // el script donde se maneja la entrada de formulario.
    data: { //puedes serializar el formulario, asi te ahorrarias indicar cada uno.
     usuario: $('input[name="txtUsuario"]').val(),
     clave: $('input[name="txtClave"]').val(),
    },
  }).then(
    function(data) {
      alert(data);
      console.log(data);
     // muestra la respuesta del php.
    }, function(data) {
      alert(data);
      console.log(data);
     // muestra un error del script.
    }, function() {
      alert(data);
      console.log(data);
     // muestra un error con la conexion.
    }
  );
  e.preventDefault(); // evitar ejecutar la acción real del formulario (submit).
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form  method="post" name="loginForm"  id="loginForm">
  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"   name="txtUsuario" placeholder="Usuario" required />          
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
    <input type="password"   class="form-control"  name='txtClave' placeholder="Clave" required />     
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-sm  btn-primary btn-block">Aceptar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Para instruirte del uso de jQuery puedes ver los siguientes enlaces:

**1.** [**Ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**2.** [**Submit**](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

**3.** [**Serialize**](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Si eres mas **audio/visual** puedes ver tutoriales en [**youtube**](http://youtube.com) acerca de jQuery. Te recomiendo uno personalmente [**codigofacilito**](https://codigofacilito.com/cursos/jquery).